PIL text issue when making gif
I'm trying to use PIL/Pillow to make a meme with a GIF. I noticed that whenever I convert it to RGB, the text is messed up(not showing up white/is somewhat transparent and black) but the background is perfect, but if I switch it to RGBA, the background gets messed up missing huge spots of color and the text is perfect. I saw something about possibly using libimagequantize but PIL doesn't come with this due to licenseing and I couldn't ever figure how to install it with it.
https://imgur.com/a/5A7OlCY <-- The middle one showed up differently when uploaded but when I download it or upload to discord it shows the same on my computer.
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageSequence
with Image.open("conch.gif") as img:
    frames = []
    for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(img):
        frame = frame.convert("RGB")
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(frame)
        font = ImageFont.truetype("./font/impacted.ttf", 30)
        text = "Hello World!"
        width, height = frame.size
        x = (width / 2) - (font.getlength(text) / 2)
        y = -5
        draw.text((x, y), text, font=font, fill="white", stroke_width=3, stroke_fill="black")
        frames.append(frame)

    frames[0].save("conchquestion.gif", save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:], loop=0, duration=img.info['duration'], transparency=0, disposal=2)

